# Prove directly from the definition of the Wiener process: $\mathbb P \left( \{W_{n^2}\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \text{ is a bounded sequence } \right) = 0$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

> Let $W_t$ - standard Wiener process. Prove directly from the definition of the Wiener process: $$\mathbb P \left( \{W_{n^2}\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \text{ is a bounded sequence } \right) = 0$$ Tip: If $(W_{n^2})_n$ is  bounded then also $(W_{n^4})_n$ is bounded.

When the sequence $\{W_{n^2}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ was limited then exist $M>0$ such that $|W_{n^2}|\le M$ for all $n\ge 1$.

From the definition of Wiener process: $$\forall_{0 \le s <t} W_t-W_s \sim \mathcal N(0,t-s)$$ so also $$W_{(n+1)^2}-W_{n^2} \sim \mathcal N(0,2n-1)$$

However, these observations don't seem to help me and I don't know what to use to prove my thesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define
$$
A_n:=\left\{\left\lvert W_{(n+1)^2}-W_{n^2}\right\rvert>\sqrt{n}\right\}.
$$
By definition of the Brownian motion, the sequence $\left(A_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is independent and $\mathbb P(A_n)=\mathbb P\left( N\sqrt{2n+
1}>\sqrt n\right)$, where $N$ has a standard normal distribution. Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(A_n)=\infty$,we conclude by the second Borel-Cantelli lemma that $\mathbb P\left(\limsup_n A_n\right)=1$ hence the probability that $\left(\left\lvert W_{(n+1)^2}-W_{n^2}\right\rvert\right)$ is bounded is $0$.

Comment: Nice, but I think you meant $\sqrt{2n+1}$ and not $\sqrt{2n-1}$.

Comment: @Will Yes, thanks.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I don't quite understand why $\mathbb P(A_n)=\mathbb P\left( N\sqrt{2n+1}>\sqrt n\right)$. Can you explain it?

Comment: $W_{(n+1)^{2}}-W_{n^{2}}$ has the same distribution as $W_{2n+1}$ @timofiej8384

Comment: It is clear, but why we can replace $W_{(n+1)^{2}}-W_{n^{2}}$ or equivalently $W_{2n+1}$ with $N\sqrt{2n+1}$?

Comment: Then use the fact that $W_t$ has the same law as $\sqrt{t}N$, where $N$ has a standard normal distribution.

Comment: Oh indeed, thanks! Last question - I don't understand how you go to the thesis of the task from Borel-Cantelli?

Comment: @timofiej8384 I have added a bit more details.